# Facebook share URL with get parameters

Tags: html, facebook

I'm trying to generate a share URL with get parameters and it's doing some double encoding shenanigans.

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bing.com%2Fsearch%3Fq%3Dkeyword" />
```

produces an error url while

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bing.com" />
```

is fine.  Anyone have ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Face problem in share my link in facebook and twitter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255896/face-problem-in-share-my-link-in-facebook-and-twitter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook share link needed to be cached on their side.  This has since be resolved on facebooks end.